# How to create a route with Strapi 4?

Tags: javascript, routes, relational-database, strapi

I am trying to set a route. I followed a tutorial.
Everything is happening in a folder inside the API folder.

Route folder contains post.js file :

```
'use strict';

/**
 * post router.
 */

const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreRouter('api::post.post', {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/posts/:id/comments',
    handler: 'posts.comments'
});
```

Controllers folder contains an other post.js file :

```
'use strict';

/**
 *  post controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::post.post', ({strapi}) => ({
    comments: async (ctx) => {
        return "Hello"
    }
}));
```

Finally, when I tested URL : http://localhost:1337/api/posts/:id/comments; I have :

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "status": 404,
        "name": "NotFoundError",
        "message": "Not Found",
        "details": {}
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong ? Is something missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the url should be like  http://localhost:1337/api/posts/1/comments and not  http://localhost:1337/api/posts/:id/comments.  Means url should provide actual id instead of ':id'.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { createCoreRouter } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;
const defaultRouter = createCoreRouter('api::post.post');

const customRouter = (innerRouter, extraRoutes = []) => {
  let routes;
  return {
    get prefix() {
      return innerRouter.prefix;
    },
    get routes() {
      if (!routes) routes = innerRouter.routes.concat(extraRoutes);
      return routes;
    },
  };
};

const myExtraRoutes = [
  {
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/api/posts/:id/comments',
    handler: 'api::post.post.comments',
  },
];
```